# How to define multiple classpaths to open a java class?

Tags: java, class, classpath

I have this bat file that it's used in windows to open a java program:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set CP=
for %%A in (lib\*) do set CP=!CP!;"%%A"
set CP=!CP:~1!
call java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp %CP%;classes br.gov.bcb.scr2.validador.desktop.ValidadorIfSwing
ENDLOCAL
```

I'm trying to run it on linux executing the following line:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp ./lib:./classes br.gov.bcb.scr2.validador.desktop.ValidadorIfSwing
```

But everytime i execute this code, i get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at br.gov.bcb.scr2.configuracao.ConfiguracaoSistema.<clinit>(ConfiguracaoSistema.java:27)
    at br.gov.bcb.scr2.validador.desktop.ValidadorIfSwing.<clinit>(ValidadorIfSwing.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

Anyone know how can i solve it ?

Comment: As you do in the Windows script, add the jars in lib to the class path individually

Comment: How can i do this in Ubuntu 20.04 @tgdavies ?

Comment: It looks like you need to convert the windows script to a linux one, this will depend on the shell you are running on Ubuntu, I would advise looking for posts/tutorials about converting windows scripts to linux scripts.